# What is the generally recommended way of creating a collection of objects in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I want to create a collection of objects that implement a given interface (in C# it would be something like `Collection<IMyInterface>`). I don't care about sorting or indexed access but would like to easily iterate over the collection with `foreach` (or the Java equivalent). It also needs to have as small a memory footprint as possible (and ideally be threadsafe).

What do you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: Side note:  The Java foreach style syntax is `for (IMyInterface item : collection)`

Answer (score 5):

You should read [Java Collections tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/) and choose what fits your needs most.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Java Collection Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html). That will introduce you to the Java collection idioms, the generics support, and what's available (briefly, [Lists](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [Sets](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and [Maps](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) - it's not clear how you want to store this data).

Without any further info, and in the most *trivial* scenario, you may want something like:

```
List<IMyInterface> list = new ArrayList<IMyInterface>();
// populate and then iterate...
list.add(new MyObject());
for (IMyInterface o : list) {
   // do something...
}
```

(ignoring thread-safety issues)

Once you're *au fait* with the standard collections, it's worth looking at more advanced options like [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) and [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/). These both offer more powerful collections and tools for iteration/manipulation.

Note (finally) that Vector and the like are advertised as being thread-safe. That (of course) only applies *per-method-call*. A collection inspection/addition operation will not be thread-safe natively and will require some extra synchronisation surround multiple operations.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use [Vector](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) which is thread-safe and will do your purpose in this case.

```
Collection<Integer> collection = new Vector<Integer>();

collection.add(1); //add something to the collection

//iterate over the collection
for(Integer test : collection) {
  //do something with 
}
```

Comment: Vector's are considered obsolete by many, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-java-vector-class-is-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet it to do one of these:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

// ...

// Thread-safe, but creates a new copy on write... so writers can write new
// values that readers won't see
List<IMyInterface> = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<IMyInterface>();
```

or

```
import java.util.*;

// ...

// also thread-safe, collection is locked during writes
List<IMyInterface> = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<IMyInterface>());
```

Edit: Another answer points out that the Vector class also implements the List interface and is thread-safe, so you could use that instead of the second option here.

Comment: You most certainly do not want to use CopyOnWriteArrayList for anything but rather specialized uses - compared to the normal collections it will be obscenely slow for write-heavy loads...

Answer (score 0):

[Java Collections Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) contains many of the classes you may find useful. They have both threadsafe and non-threadsafe candidates.

Comment: It's worth noting that the above link is to a very old version of the Java API. It's so old that it precedes Generics, which should be used for any new Java development.

Comment: This is the correct link: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html